# Specific user action triggers a git commit. How can I prevent multiple actions on same directory from not locking and throwing an error?

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

I have an app that uses libgit2sharp to do some git actions behind the scenes. When a user does a specific action, a git commit gets triggered. It's possible that the user can click a button multiple times quickly, triggering multiple commits at the same time. When this happens, sometime one of these errors happens:

`the index is locked; this might be due to a concurrent or crashed process`
`LibGit2Sharp.LockedFileException: failed to create locked file`

What's the correct way to prevent this? The code that causes this looks like this:

```
using (Repository repo = new Repository(workingDirectory))
{    
            var stat = repo.RetrieveStatus();
            if (!stat.IsDirty)
            {
                return;
            }

            Commands.Stage(repo, "*");

            Signature committer = new Signature(email, email, DateTime.UtcNow);
            repo.Commit("commit!", committer, committer);
}
```

Is there some way I can check if a lock already exists and wait? Is there a better pattern?

Comment: The most correct way is to separate event receiving and handling. On an event do not call handler — just put the received event into a queue. Separate process (or thread) processes event from the queue one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way of limiting additional key presses until the first command completes.  There are many possible ways to do this, but just the code shown does not give enough information to answer completely - the fix needs to be at the point that you call this routine.

Decide whether you want to ignore extra keypresses while a command is ongoing, or whether you want to queue them (save them and execute them in order after the original command completes).  For simplicity, and based on this being multiple presses, I'd probably start out just ignoring extra presses.  Another option would be to deactivate the key after it is pressed, until the command completes.

If you can't figure out a way to get feedback on the commit completing, a hacky method to just get things working temporarily would be just to put a timer on it, and drop multiple commands until the timer is done - maybe 5 seconds or so?  But that should just be a quick fix if you have users currently using the product, while you figure out a more permanent solution.